# How to fetch account in mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am implementing a web-app using a **three layered architecture** with **express** and **docker**. I am also using **mysql** to store accounts. This is my **initialize-database.sql** file:

```
CREATE TABLE accounts(
    personId INT NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    userPassword VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,    
    CONSTRAINT id_pk PRIMARY KEY (personId)
)
```

In my *data-access layer* I have the **account-repository** file that sends queries to the database:

```
const db = require('./db')
exports.getAccount = function(username, userPassword, callback){

    const query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND userPassword = ?"
    const values = [username, userPassword]

    db.query(query, values, function(error, account){

        if(error){
            callback("DatabaseError", null)
        }else{
            callback(account)
        }
    })
}
```

Now in my **app.js** file I want to check if the account exists when logging in:

```
app.post("/login", function(request, response){

    var username = request.body.username
    var userPassword = request.body.password
    if (username && userPassword) {
        account.getAccount(username, userPassword, function(error, result){

            if(error){
                response.send("<h1>Error with database</h1>")
            }
            if(result){
                request.session.isLoggedIn = true
                request.session.username = username
                response.redirect("/")
            }
        })
    }   
})
```

But here I get an error that says that result is **null**. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you're defining result as null in your callback if there's an error: `callback("DatabaseError", null)` and if it's successful you're not passing along the result, so it's also `null`: `callback(account)`. So basically `result` will always be null based on how you're calling the function either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be an easy fix, you just need to change the getAccount function like so:

```
const db = require('./db')
exports.getAccount = function(username, userPassword, callback){

    const query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = ? AND userPassword = ?"
    const values = [username, userPassword]

    db.query(query, values, function(error, account){

        if(error){
            callback("DatabaseError", null)
        }else{
            callback(null, account)
        }
    })
}
```

The first argument to the callback should be any error that occurred, therefore this should be *null* when the query succeeds!

Comment: Yes that did it! Thank you

Comment: Great, glad to be of help!